# How do I base64 encode an image blob received from an API inside Ionic2?

Tags: image, base64, ionic2

I call the Dropbox API `get_thumbnail` method, it returns an image blob. I want to base64 encode this so that i can use it in an  tag inside the html.

Trying to use the installed `node_module` called `base64-img`, 
How can I import `base64-img` module in to my `.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
var base64Img = require('base64-img');
...
// use it like this
// Async
base64Img.img('data:image/png;base64,...', 'dest', '1', function(err, filepath) {});
// Sync
var filepath = base64Img.imgSync('data:image/png;base64,...', '', '2');
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but am I missing something with the 'require' ? Because it says "Unresolved function or method require()".I tried to use an import at the top of my home.ts file like this `import { base64Img } from '../../../node_modules/base64-img/base64-img';`

Comment: But it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'base64Img'". Looks like it just cannot find that library

Comment: I was using PHPStorm which didn't have the correct libraries installed, so switched to Webstorm 11 trial, which cancels the error above, but now when hovering over enquire, it says: 
`TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'`